# git push via gitlab CI runner failed with 403 error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-push

I have a gitlab runner for git project **A**, I want the CI runner run some scripts everytime there ar commits from **A** and push the results to project **B**, but when pushing to project **B** but I got:

`"fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.<mycompanyname>.com/<myprojectname>.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"`

I managed to push the changes manually on the machine where the CI runner locates, but always push fail via CI runner.

I tried:

1. add the runner to project as developer
2. change the local git config file to `https://<runner_name>@gitlab.*.git`

But still doesn't work, anyone can help here?